# How implement node-deeplink with http end point in node.js

Tags: android, node.js, http, deep-linking

I have done the DeepLink by referring this(i.e ***https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-deeplink***)and it is working good and fine.But I have to implement same with http server end point so for that I have created one http server and listening on port 2000.My deeplink is http://host:2000/deep?url=nofer
 Now My server is handling request as

```
var http = require('http'); 
var deeplink = require('node-deeplink');
http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(2000);
function handleRequest(request, response){
    try {
        //log the request on console
        console.log(request.url);
       if(request.url=="/deep"){                
            deeplink({  
                fallback: 'http://na.nofer.com',
                android_package_name: 'com.na.nofer'    
            });

       }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

app is not installed in my android device .once i have request with http://host:2000/deep?url=nofer in android browser ,request is landing but it is not directing to neighter fallback nor app store.

Can some one suggest on same.